# How can i hide the standard popup alert?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable the automatic popup alert box because i already have a warning installed (see red text)[image]

Translation: 'wachtwoord' = password, 'herhaal wachtwoord' = repeat password

The alert box (also the red text) = The password needs to contain at leat 8 characters, 1 capital, 1 number and 1 special character.

Can i fix it by adding a single line of code? Or how do i do it?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you are handling form validation manually you can add ```noValidate``` attribute to the ```from``` element like this : 

```<form novalidate>```

Answer (score 0):

Wiljan! It's hard to say for sure without seeing the code. Try moving your password validation to an event listener that runs when you click the button to submit all the password data!